# Powershell secure string encryption

Tags: powershell

How is secure string encrypted? I've [read](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/11/24/saving-passwords-and-preventing-other-processes-from-decrypting-them/) that it uses DPAPI, but what if I'm using AsPlainText? Does it still uses DPAPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you linked to starts its second paragraph with:

> The `ConvertFrom-SecureString` and `ConvertTo-SecureString` cmdlets, when
>   you don’t use their -Key, -SecureKey, or -AsPlainText switches, use
>   DPAPI to encrypt / decrypt your secret data.

So no, if you use `-AsPlainText` it is not encrypted and doesn't use DPAPI.

When it is encrypted, the key is specific to the user *and* computer on which you've done the encryption.

According to [the `ConvertFrom-SecureString` documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849814.aspx), if you use `-Key` or `-SecureKey`, then AES is used. As for how DPAPI encrypts data, have a look at [this MSDN article about Windows Data Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). One of its points says:

> It uses proven cryptographic routines, such as the strong Triple-DES
>   algorithm in CBC mode, the strong SHA-1 algorithm, and the PBKDF2
>   password-based key derivation routine.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how that was done. Is it still 3DES? And what information from the user and computer is obtained?